# grouping sorted list using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to combine several files into a single one using a flat reference file. My flat file looks as follows :

```
master_A | SubA | SubSubA
master_A | SubA | SubSubB
master_A | SubA | SubSubC
master_A | SubB | SubSubA
master_B | SubC | SubSubA
master_B | SubC | SubSubB
...
```

Column B and C combined define my file location on disc and I want to use this flow to generate single files based on the grouped values of column A (the masters).

In other words, above example would result is 2 files, and the sub files would be added. So the flow would be as follows:

Generate a file called master_A.txt and add the content of SubA_SubSubA.txt, SubA_SubSubB.txt, SubA_SubSubC.txt and SubB_SubSubA.txt.

Next, generate master_B and add the content of SubC_SubSubA.txt and SubC_SubSubB.txt

And continue until end of reference file...

I didn't get much further than below to be honest...

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (myFlatFile.txt) do (

set myMaster=%%i
set myFile=%%j_%%k.txt

rem if myMaster differs from the previous one generate a new file using myMaster
rem as filename, then add myFile content untill the master changes again. 
rem What would be the best way to achieve this ?

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=| " %%i in (myFlatFile.txt) do (
   type %%j_%%k.txt >> %%i.txt
)
```

The only problem with previous code is if the master... files may exist before the program run. In this case, a previous file delete cycle fix the problem.